# Restricted OLS problem

Tags: regression, least-squares, proof, constrained-regression, restrictions

Here is my problem:

Let $1\leq l<k$ be integers and write the design matrix $X$ as $X=[X_1\; X_2]$, where $X_1$ is an $n\times l$-dimensional matrix, and where $X_2$ is an $n\times (k-l)$-dimensional matrix. Show that the restricted LS estimator $\beta^*$ subject to the restriction $R\beta=r$ with $R=[I_l\;\, 0]$ and $r=0$ satisfies $\beta^*=(0,[(X_2'X_2)^{-1}X_2'Y]')'$.

My solution:
\begin{equation} 
(X^TX)=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} X_1^TX_1 \quad X_1^TX_2 \\ X_2^TX_1 \quad X_2^TX_2 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

$$R(X^TX)^{-1}R^T = (X_1^TX_1 - X_1^TX_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TX_1)^{-1}$$

$$R\hat\beta - r = (I_l:0)\hat\beta  = (\hat\beta_l :0)$$

\begin{equation} 
(X^TX)^{-1}R^T=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} X_1^TX_1(X_1^TX_1 - X_1^TX_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TX_1)^{-1}  \\ (X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2X_1((X_1^TX_1 - X_1^TX_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TX_1)^{-1} \quad  \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

But then when I multiply all terms I got

\begin{equation} 
\beta^*= \hat\beta - \left( \begin{array} {c,c} \hat\beta \quad 0 \\ BA\hat\beta_ \quad 0 \end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

where $B = (X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2X_1((X_1^TX_1 - X_1^TX_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TX_1)^{-1}$

and $A = (X_1^TX_1 - X_1^TX_2(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^TX_1)^{-1}$

So I during multiplication I did something wrong. Can you give me a hint, how should I solve this problem(maybe some clever trick in order to make multiplication a bit easier)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restriction just says that the variables in $X_1$ do not enter the regression, so that the formula constrains those coefficients to zero, and the others then are the standard OLS coefficients of a regression of $y$ on $X_2$.

Here is an implementation in R (a more formal answer follows below):

```
library(lrmest)
# example data
n <- 100
k_1 <- 3
k_2 <- 4
X_1 <- matrix(rnorm(n*k_1),ncol=k_1)
X_2 <- matrix(rnorm(n*k_2),ncol=k_2)
y <- rnorm(n)
X <- cbind(X_1,X_2)

# implementing the restriction in lm directly
coef(lm(y~X_2-1))

> 
       X_21        X_22        X_23        X_24 
-0.02171519 -0.04595167  0.08971665  0.04871940 

# restricted least squares
R <- cbind(diag(k_1),matrix(0,nrow=k_1,ncol=k_2))
r <- delta <- rep(0,k_1)
rls(y~X-1,r,R,delt=delta)

> 
$`*****Restricted Least Square Estimator*****`
   Estimate Standard_error t_statistic pvalue
X1   0.0000         0.0000           0      1
X2   0.0000         0.0000           0      1
X3   0.0000         0.0000           0      1
X4  -0.0217         0.0960          NA     NA
X5  -0.0460         0.1091          NA     NA
X6   0.0897         0.1093          NA     NA
X7   0.0487         0.0922          NA     NA
```

Both question and answer make use of properties of restricted OLS, which are for example discussed further [here](http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/xplore/tutorials/xegbohtmlnode18.html).

In particular, the restricted OLS estimator is related to the unrestricted one via
$$
\beta^*=\hat\beta+(X^TX)^{-1}R^T[R(X^TX)^{-1}R^T]^{-1}(r-R\hat\beta)
$$

Algebraically, the mistake seems to be in
$$R\hat\beta - r = (I_l:0)\hat\beta,$$ which is just $\hat\beta_l$.

In more detail, denote 
\begin{align*} 
(X^TX)^{-1}&=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} X_1^TX_1&X_1^TX_2  \\ X_2^TX_1&X_2^TX_2\end{array} \right)^{-1}\\&\equiv\left( \begin{array} {c,c} \tilde A&\tilde B  \\ \tilde C&\tilde D\end{array} \right)
\end{align*}
Then, 
$$R(X^TX)^{-1}R^T = \tilde A$$
and
$$(X^TX)^{-1}R^T = \left( \begin{array} {c} \tilde A \\ \tilde C\end{array} \right)$$
leading to
\begin{align*} 
\beta^*&= \left( \begin{array} {c} \hat\beta_l \\ \hat\beta_k\end{array} \right) - \left( \begin{array} {c,c} \tilde A \\ \tilde C\end{array} \right)\tilde A^{-1}R\hat\beta\\
&= \left( \begin{array} {c} \hat\beta_l \\ \hat\beta_k\end{array} \right) - \left( \begin{array} {c,c} I \\ \tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\end{array} \right)\hat\beta_l\\
\end{align*}
Thus, using 
$$
\hat\beta=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} \tilde A&\tilde B  \\ \tilde C&\tilde D\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array} {c} X_1^Ty\\X_2^Ty\end{array} \right),
$$
we have
$$
\hat\beta_k=\tilde C X_1^Ty+\tilde DX_2^Ty
$$
and
$$
\hat\beta_l=\tilde A X_1^Ty+\tilde BX_2^Ty
$$
so that
$$
\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\hat\beta_l=\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde A X_1^Ty+\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde BX_2^Ty
$$
and 
\begin{align*} 
\hat\beta_k-\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\hat\beta_l&=\tilde C X_1^Ty+\tilde DX_2^Ty-
\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde A X_1^Ty-\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde BX_2^Ty\\
&=(\tilde D-\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde B)X_2^Ty
\end{align*}
Now, use [results for partitioned inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix)
\begin{align*} 
(X^TX)^{-1}
&=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} \tilde A&\tilde B  \\ \tilde C&\tilde D\end{array} \right)\\&=
\left( \begin{array} {c,c} A&B  \\ C&D\end{array} \right)^{-1}\\
&=\left( \begin{array} {c,c} E&-EBD^{-1}  \\ -D^{-1}CE&D^{-1}+D^{-1}CEBD^{-1}\end{array} \right)\\
\end{align*}
where $E=(A-BD^{-1}C)^{-1}$.

Hence,
\begin{align*} 
\tilde D-\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\tilde B&=D^{-1}+D^{-1}CEBD^{-1}-D^{-1}CEE^{-1}EBD^{-1}\\&=D^{-1}
\end{align*}
The result is complete by noting that
$$D^{-1}=(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}$$
so that 
$$\hat\beta_k-\tilde C\tilde A^{-1}\hat\beta_l=(X_2^TX_2)^{-1}X_2^Ty$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the full description of problem:)
Very helpful!